# Observer usage Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

Can I use one observer named "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" in two different custom modules?

Comment: why you want to do that ? do you want to use that observer to call your observer or you want to name your observer to "checkout_onepage_conroller_action"

Comment: Yes you can in any number of modules.

Comment: Yes, you can use it. **@Bunny**

Answer (score 0):

How to create and call your observer :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="easypay_controller_success_action" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutSuccessObserver"/>
</event>
</config>
```

Create a folder and file \Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutSuccessObserver.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;


class CheckoutSuccessObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_order;

    protected $_scopeConfig;

    protected $_postPay;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
) {
    // Code here
   }

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  // code here
}
}

}
```